# Loading PHP file with AJAX (Get URL of the page where it's loaded)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My question is: How to get the URL of webpage where php file is loaded with ajax?
I need to get this variable within ajax file not the main page file.

Everything works perfectly when I manually add the URL of a webpage to retrieve facebook likes:

```
$facebooklikesURL = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

but I want to make it dynamic. I'm using wordpress, but it looks like when you're loading file via Ajax, it ignores any functions outside the file - like get_the_permalink(); .

I tried this method:

```
$facebooklikesURL ="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

... but it retrieves **file location** (which I'm loading with ajax) not the **Webpage URL** where it's loaded.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can pass the Url from where Ajax call has been sent using javascript!

Comment: have you tried this $facebooklikesURL ="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]";

Comment: You should also quote indices of the array:
$facebooklikesURL = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];